# How to use C# class as data source

Tags: c#, dataset

How to use C# class as Data Source and Bind with DataSet. Do I need to use some special tag to   mark the data fields?

Comment: ASP.NET/MVC/WPF/Winforms?

Comment: No, you just need to return a queryable or list of objects rather than a single class.  That's what the DataSource is expecting.

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx `BaseDataBoundControl.DataSource` expects `Object` you should just try setting the `DataSource` as a `List<YourClass>`

Comment: `DataSource` This is the primary property to which you assign your data. You can assign anything that implements the `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList`, or `IBindingListView` interface. Some examples of items that can be assigned to the `DataSource` property are arrays (`IList`), lists (`IList`), data tables (`IListSource`), and data sets (`IListSource`).

Comment: I am trying Winforms. I am trying to use the GridView control. I have previously used gridview control using a SQlite data source. I saw the option of object list view but could not find out the proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a class, or a collection of your class?

To use your class directly, you'll need to implement your class so it inherits a collection interface like `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you just have a list of your classes, then that should work directly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple class cannot be a data source to a DataSet object as others have said. With data-binding you can indeed bind a Control to a single class and its properties as is the case with data-binding in WPF. However, since you mentioned a DataSet specifically, the DataSet itself is a collection of tables (DataTables) and relationships so it is an aggregate object and therefore a simple class won't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`DataSource` = How you connect to your database
`DataSet` = Structure of your database in memory

DataSource This is the primary property to which you assign your data. You can
assign anything that implements the IList, IListSource, IBindingList, or IBindingListView
interface. Some examples of items that can be assigned to the DataSource property are
arrays (IList), lists (IList), data tables (IListSource), and data sets (IListSource).

DataSet is a memory-based, tabular, relational representation of data and is the primary disconnected data object. Conceptually, think of DataSet as an in-memory relational database, but it’s simply cached data and doesn’t provide any of the transactional properties (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) that are essential to today’s relational databases. DataSet contains a collection of DataTable and DataRelation objects

**From:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326218/335216